# Construct and process multidimensional arrays/objects in ES6? (flatten/fold?)

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

I have:

```
      for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(JSON.parse($settingsField.val()))) {
        for (const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(value1)) {
          for (const [key3, value3] of Object.entries(value2)) {
            helper.appendRow([key1, key2, key3, value3]);
          }
        }
      }
```

and to create the settings array I have

```
          if (!result[values[0]]) {
            result[values[0]] = {};
          }
          if (!result[values[0]][values[1]]) {
            result[values[0]][values[1]] = {};
          }
          result[values[0]][values[1]][values[2]] = values[3];
```

I am trying to convert between two data structures:

```
{
  "key_level1": {
    "key_level2": {
      "key_level3_1": "value1",
      "key_level3_2": "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
[
  ["key_level1", "key_level2", "key_level3_1", "value1"], 
  ["key_level1", "key_level2", "key_level3_2", "value2"]
]
```

Comment: Eh, what's the question here? I think you've got a solution already?

Comment: Both of them are crying for generalization via recursion.

Answer (score 0):

First half:

```
function helper(o) {
    this.object = (o, keys) => {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(o)) this[typeof(value)](value, keys.concat(key))
    };
    this.string = (s, keys) => console.log(s, keys);
    return this.object(o, []);
}
```

I couldn't get it working without the `{}` around the `for` not sure what's up with that.

Second half:

```
function x(a, result = {}, depth = 0) {
    v = a.pop();
    result = depth ? {...{[v]: result}} : v;
    return a.length ? x(a, result, depth + 1) : result;
}
```

`depth` is not strictly required but I found it better than `Object.keys(result).length`.

They are not necessarily better than the originals. In fact, they are much less maintainable.